# How to keep CMake-QT generated MOCs in individual obj files?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake, linker

Is it possible to have CMake-QT generate individual .obj files during AUTOMOC thus allowing for Whole Program Optimization during link time?
If yes - how?

**TLDR - Pseudologic:**

`CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON => [mocs_compilation.obj != (moc_a.obj moc_b.obj)] => linker(one_instead_of_many.obj)? dependency missing : no dependency missing`

### Situation

When I set `CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON` in a Project, a file named `mocs_compilation.cpp` is created in the `<project_name>_autogen` folder which includes the AUTOMOCed files and thus creates **one** object instead of several individual files.

### Why I think it is important?

Using Link Time Code Generation/Whole Program Optimization in Visual Studio 2015 our build (with custom moc-generation steps and individual .boj files) works without problems - possibly getting rid of unnecessary .obj files thus even eliminating a dependency to an extra LIB/DLL.

PS: By the way I really think there should be a cmake-qt tag if anyone cares to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a general issue with CMake:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17277